# JSON object returned to bash need to extract key value

Tags: json, bash, curl

I have a curl command that gets a JSON response and it gives the response below. I need to get the value of `data.value`

How can I do this without a "*hacky*" solution?

```
{
    "request_id":"50aaabe7-d01b-0a83-da86-8f01cb1da74b",
    "lease_id":"",
    "renewable":false,
    "lease_duration":2764800,
    "data":{"value":"randomBinaryString"},
    "wrap_info":null,
    "warnings":null,
    "auth":null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install `jq`, then it is as easy as:

```
<curl-command> | jq .data.value
```

If you don't want to install extra software and the response is always in that format, you can do some dirty tricks:

```
<curl-command> | grep data | tr '":{' '   ' | awk '{print $3}'
```

Comment: Do note the entry for questions which "have already been asked and answered many times before" in the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Leaving in the hackish section (when the OP explicitly asks for a non-hacky solution) is... maybe not ideal. If you *were* going to do an ugly hack that's extremely dependent on formatting and data contents and broken in most cases, though, there's little reason for all three of `grep`, `tr` and `awk`; awk alone can do the work of all three. `awk -F'[":{[:space:]]+' '/"data":/ { print $3 }'`, for example (ugh, I feel dirty typing that).

Comment: Completely agree. It is just that It was easier for me to think in other terms instead of the field separator string. As you said, that part was the backup (and non requested), the good answer is the first part. BTW, "hacky" can have lots of meanings. My answer uses less special characters than yours, so don't appear to be as much hacky as yours (despite is the same) XD